# Invoke-WebRequest with SSL and Proxy Autentication

Tags: powershell, ssl, powershell-3.0

I've to make a web request to an HTTPS URL (SSL3 protocol) on my proxy network.

My code is this:

```
$UserName = "domain\user"
$SecurePassword = ("YourPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'

$Credentials = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePassword)

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri "https://www.google.it" -Proxy "http://proxy:8080" -ProxyCredential $Credentials
```

Note that the URL https://www.google.it is an example. I've to do it with an HTTPS URL with protocol SSL3 (it's an old standard).

Output of my web request is:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Could you help me please? I don't understand where I'm wrong.

Comment: UP! UP! UP! UP! UP! :(